# A value of type 'DateTime?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'String'.

TextEditingController dateInput = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.initialValue != null) {
       dateInput.text = widget.initialValue;
    }
  }
```

error A value of type 'DateTime?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'String'.

Comment: Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'String'.

Comment: how can i do it? sorry i'm new @Riwen

Comment: change your code `widget.initialValue.toString()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateFormat` from [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package to format your `DateTime` Object to whatever format you want to display.

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

TextEditingController dateInput = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.initialValue != null) {
     // Format date to whichever format you want to display
     String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd – kk:mm').format(widget.initialValue!);
       dateInput.text = formattedDate;
    }
  }
```

Comment: The argument type 'DateTime?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime'. @usama-karim

Comment: Because `initialValue` is `nullable` so it's required to use bang operator (!). I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can change the initial value to string by using the toString() function like this:

```
dateInput.text = widget.initialValue.toString();
```